# Matlab: Regexp excluding decimal point from extracting

Tags: regex, matlab

I'd like to match sample text to my desired text:

Sample:

```
A1.24(B,A2.45(A.46(D,X)))
```

Desired :

```
A1.24 B A2.45 A.46 D X
```

I wanted to use regexp(Sample,'\W') but it includes decimal point too and returns location numbers which include the decimal point too. but I do want to exclude decimal point and keep the rest. would you mind helping me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply try this pattern:

```
/[(|)|,]/g
```

#### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yC1tI7/2)